# British 80s TV series about a toy soldier played by a real actor

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a live-action TV serial which I'm pretty sure was made in the UK during the 80s. It had a similar level of production as [The Box of Delights](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0086675/).

All I can really remember is the main character was a toy soldier. There's one scene where there is cannon fire and another soldier exclaims "you'll be blown to smithereens", and another scene where he's trying to climb a set of stairs built for full height humans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Quincy's Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quincy%27s_Quest) (1979).

> In a department store the unwanted toys are set to be destroyed. One
> of the rejects, a doll named Quincy, goes on a quest to find the store
> Santa Claus who is the only person who can save them.

A toy soldier (played by Tommy Steele) needs to get to the top of a flight of stairs in one scene.

Note also that being destroyed or broken-up is described (repeatedly) as being "*smithereened*"

Comment: Gotta love this site and how some people can find the answer with such little detail. I found a more complete version at https://youtu.be/kgKclRDKyIc and the battlefield and General's scene about 40 minutes definitely matches what I remember.

Comment: @HorusKol - Feel free to drop a better quality video in :-)